# Software to simulate mechanical systems

Tags: simulation

I wish to achieve the following :-

1. Simulate the motion of a 4 wheel toy car on a rough surface.
2. Get the mechanical stresses during the motion on various parts and joints of the car.
3. Get the forces being acted on the wheels during the entire motion.
4. Provision for providing various input data like friction, wheel speed, gravity forces.
5. Free/paid: Both is okay. I would prefer having a software with good online help community or good tutorials for that.

System preferred: Windows 7 and above.

Comment: Free or paid software?

Comment: @EricShain - both is okay. I would prefer having a software with good online help community or good tutorials for that.